# SQL Joining Information From 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I know questions similar to mine have been answered elsewhere but I can't seem to figure this out for my scenario.

I have 2 tables, a `[Request]` table used to store requests and a `[Log]` table used to store status changes performed on the requests. I am working on a reporting app that currently returns information about the status changes for each request using an `INNER JOIN` on the `RequestID` from both tables. That looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Log].[Column1], [Request].[Column2], [Request].[Column3] 
FROM 
    [Log] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Request] ON [Log].[RequestID] = [Request].[ID]
```

Here is my problem: I've been asked to expand the report to include the request's action. I'll explain. Each request has a type associated with it. If the type is `SMP` I need to include the `Action` from a third `[SMP_Request]` table and include it as a column in my report. If the type isn't `SMP`, that column is just left blank. I'm sure it's also important to note that the `[SMP_Request]` table also has a `RequestID` field we can use to match everything up.

I'm trying to figure out how to craft my query to include this `Action` column from the `[SMP_Request]` table but I'm struggling to get it right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error?   Please post your query attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Left Join.

```
SELECT [Log].[Column1], [Request].[Column2], [Request].[Column3] , IsNull([SMP_Request].[Action], '') as Action
    FROM [Log]
         INNER JOIN [Request] ON [Log].[RequestID] = [Request].[ID]
         LEFT JOIN [SMP_Request] ON [SMP_Request].[RequestID] = [Request].[ID]
```

This will give you if there's any action to the request and in case that is not, will return a Blank Space

[Check here more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT [Log].[Column1], [Request].[Column2], [Request].[Column3], smp.Action
FROM [Log] 
   INNER JOIN [Request] ON [Log].[RequestID] = [Request].[ID]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN SMP_Request smp ON (Request.ID = smp.RequestID AND smp.type == 'the type you care about')
```